# Span not rendering in google chrome

Tags: css

I've got a `div` with a background image which contains a `span` with `height` and `width` `100%`. I have it set up that the `span` has a `background-color: black` with `opacity: 0`. When the `div` is hovered the opacity of the `span` increases in order to darken the background image. The problem I'm having is that when I hover , the span covers the entire `div` as desired but when I mouse off the `span` is only covering a portion of the `div`, sometimes from the top and sometimes from the bottom. Works fine in Safari and Firefox. The problem is specific to Chrome.

```css
.covers span {
  display: block;
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.2;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.covers:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="covers" id="cover-stories">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the span have any ancestors with a specified height?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Changing the code into a snippet doesn't really do much.

Comment: @MrLister - I know :)

Comment: @mccavandish Perhaps this is a problem with using an inline element to represent a block element. Have you tried replacing the span with a div?

Comment: Put width: 100% in the div.